# How can I toggle Line Wrap/Word Wrap in VS Code Markdown Preview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, editor, word-wrap

I usually use `Alt + z` to toggle the Editor `Line Wrap/Word Wrap`.

But how can I do that in `Markdown Preview`?

The default status of `Markdown Preview` is `Line Wrap/Word Warp` **on**, just like the screenshot bellow does.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBscL.png)

I want to turn **off** the `Line Wrap/Word Wrap` to shrink the length of the `Markdown Preview`

Comment: possibly (at least historically somewhat) related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15921 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25357

Answer (score 1):

`View: Toggle Word Wrap` (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) doesn't (at the time of this writing) affect the Markdown Preview.

You can at least though use the `editor.wordWrap` setting. Ex. to disable word wrap:

```json
"[markdown]": {
   "editor.wordWrap": "off"
}
```

Possibly (at least historically somewhat) related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15921 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25357.

As a workaround, apparently you can put things in something like a `<div style="width: 1500px">` ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs-authoring/issues/932)). But if you're going to do stuff like that, I think you might as well use the `markdown.styles` setting (see also [the related docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_using-your-own-css)) and write some CSS that disables line wrapping by changing the `white-space`, `word-wrap`, or `word-break` property values

Comment: Appreciate for your answer, tho it doesn't meet my need. 

I found a quite brutal way to achieve the goal, from the link here.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs-authoring/issues/932

Comment: @jiaxianghuang edited that info into the answer post and some other info as well.

Comment: Thanks again! I will try it later.

PS.

I ought to vote you up, But one embarassing thing is I am not able to cast a vote on you cause I dont even have 15 `reputation` to do that.